# Excluding contents of <span> from text using Waitr

Tags: ruby, watir

#### Watir

```
mytext =browser.element(:xpath => '//*[@id="gold"]/div[1]/h1').text
```

#### Html

```
<h1>
 This is the text I want
 <span> I do not want this text </span>
</h1>
```

When I run my Watir code, it selects all the text, including what is in the spans. How do I just get the text "This is the text I want", and no span text?

Comment: Well, you are asking for the text of the `h1`, so you shouldn't be surprised that's what you're getting. Are you asking "How do I remove any text inside a `<span>`?"

Comment: Yes, how do I remove the span text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a more complicated HTML, I find it can be easier to deal with this using Nokogiri as it provides more methods for parsing the HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'

h1 = browser.element(:xpath => '//*[@id="gold"]/div[1]/h1')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(h1.html)
mytext = doc.at('h1').children.select(&:text?).map(&:text).join.strip
```

Comment: you can also use watigiri and `#text!` to still use Watir locators with Nokogiri. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally start by trying to avoid using XPath. One of the most powerful features of Watir is the ability to create complicated locators without XPath syntax.
The issue is that calling text on a node gets all content within that node. You'd need to do something like:

```
top_level = browser.element(id: 'gold')
h1_text = top_level.h1.text
span_text = top_level.h1.span.text
desired_text = h1_text.chomp(span_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is useful for top level text.

If there is only one h1, you can ommit id

`@b.h1.text.remove(@b.h1.children.collect(&:text).join(' '))`

Or specify it if there are more

`@b.h1(id: 'gold').text.remove(@b.h1.children.collect(&:text).join(' '))`

Make it a method and call it from your script with `get_top_text(@b.h1)` to get it

```
def get_top_text(el)
    el.text.chomp(@b.h1.children.collect(&:text).join(' '))
end
```